# Does order by column need to be part of an index

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table foo (id, name varchar(255));
create table foo_values (id, foo_id, name varchar(255), value varchar(255));

create table bar (id, name varchar(255));
create table bar_values (id, bar_id, name varchar(255), position integer);
```

Our queries are going to look like

```
select * from foo_values where foo_id=<foo_id> and name=<some-name> order by value;
select * from bar_values where bar_id=<bar_id> and name=<some-name> order by position;

We have a multi key index for foo_id and name in foo_values.
We have a multi key index for bar_id and name in bar_values.
```

Does it make sense to include value and position in their respective key indexes or is it not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The ORDER BY keyword is used to sort the result-set by a specified column.
- The ORDER BY keyword sort the records in ascending order by default.
- If you want to sort the records in a descending order, you can use the DESC keyword.

So, **No**, the order by does not need to be part of an index.
**Although, if there are millions of records, you should make an index for each of them.**

Comment: It will be slower if you will add third column to multi key index.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, I don't think its going to make a difference, see if you can measure it.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can order by any column, indexed or not, but having it indexed may speed up the query.

Comment: No! I dont' think so. I think DBMS deals with result set from main WHERE clause and do sorting on that result set with respect to  ORDER BY independently without referring to INDEX.

Answer (score 2):

If you add value to the foo index and position to the bar index it would likely be faster, but only for these queries and it would slow performance (especially if those columns aren't relatively static, since the index keys will move) on writes.

So it could make sense (if there are a lot of rows to be sorted within that key).

The best way to see the effects of an index are to use EXPLAIN to look at the execution plan with and without a particular index.